# Multidimensional navigational properties in Entity Framework 6 Code First

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to figure out if something like this this possible:

Suppose I have the following model of a sports team:

Person( ID, Name, Roles)

Role ( Person, Title) ex: Owner, Player, Coach, ... a Person can have more than one role ( A player can be an owner for example)

Now lets say that I want to create a team Model something like this:

```
public class Team {
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public virtual Dictionary<Role, List<Person>> TeamMemebers {get; set; }
}
```

vs doing something like this:

```
    public class Team {
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public virtual  List<Person>> Players {get; set; }
    public virtual  List<Person>> Owners {get; set; }
    public virtual  List<Person>> Coaches {get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I am trying to figure out if this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: `Entity Framework` does not support Dictionary mappings you would either have to do a manual mapping or go with option 2.

Comment: Could this be done for a List<List<Person>>?

Comment: I meant to say array.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only select on this property then I would create one **partial** class for model (as in your 2nd snippet) and another one for custom methods and properties.

And there I would add

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped] 
Dictionary<Role, List<Person>> TeamMemebers 
{
   get
   {
       // return select mapped to dictionary
   }
}
```